# How to invoke asyncio code that blocks, and reach the next line?

Tags: python-asyncio, blocking

How can I invoke `f` and reach the next line?

```
from SomeLib import f
f()
print('never reaches')
```

I would prefer not to mess with the internals of 'SomeLib', but f it's a quick fix I'll do it:

```
def f():
    asyncio.get_event_loop.run_until_complete(ag())

async def ag():
    async with websockets.client.connect(...) as websocket:
        :
        await wait_for_recv(...)

async def wait_for_recv(...):
    while True:
        message = await asyncio.wait_for(websocket.recv(), timeout=time_out)
        process(message)
```

Calling `ag` directly is an option, but how to do it?

I've tried using a thread.
I've tried executors.
I've tried `new_event_loop`.

I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution. I suspect it is terrible, so I would appreciate feedback.

At the callsite:

```
worker_thread = threading.Thread(target=worker)
worker_thread.start()

def worker:
    f()
```

And fiddling the library:

```
def f():
    self.loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(self.loop)

    self.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(ag)

# added this
def kill(self):
    self.loop.stop()
```

Comment: It's not terrible, that's the only way to do background execution if you need to mix sync and async code. With an all-async code base you wouldn't need to do that because you'd use `asyncio.create_task(ag())` and continue with other async code with `ag` running in the "background".